# Passing value from javascript to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE (a rich text editor in js).
Currently, I have a function as such:

```
   function GetEditorValue() {
        var val = tinyMCE.get('valueTextArea').getContent()

    }
```

which returns the text that was entered into the rich text editor. 
Now, is there a way to pass this data using POST to my mvc controller
and access it there?
(All this is being done in ASP.NET MVC 2 using C#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send this value using AJAX. For example [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) provides the [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function:

```
var val = tinyMCE.get('valueTextArea').getContent();
$.post('<%= Url.Action("foo") %>', { value: val }, function(result) {
    // TODO: handle the success
    alert('the value was successfully sent to the server');
});
```

and inside your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string value)
{
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Now obviously because this is a RichText editor the value might contain dangerous characters and ASP.NET will reject them by throwing an exception. To avoid this you could decorate your controller action with the [`[ValidateInput(false)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Foo(string value)
{
    // Do something with the value
}
```

and if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 you should also add the following to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the answer even though in my case my controller method is not being called. However I will figure that part out myself. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @snwr, maybe there's some javascript error? What does `FireBug` says? Can you see the AJAX request being sent?

Comment: No javascript errors and my $.post is definitely being hit according to firebug (and passing on the correct value for the parameter). However my break point at the controller is not being hit..

Comment: Actually, I fixed that problem. still, string is null inside of the controller method however (though the controller is being called)

Comment: @snwr, when when you look with the request in FireBug you should see `value=somevalue` being sent in the POST body. Then in your controller action you should be able to get back the `value`. Note that the parameter name in your controller action should match the name of the POSTed value parameter.

Comment: ahhh I had no idea that the names had to be equal. that was the problem mate. thanks a bunch for your wonderful help.